# How get data from string like query string with php?

Tags: php, get, query-string

I have url like this

1. index.php?name=aya&age=29
2. index.php?name:aya&age:29

I want get name and age from this url.
I think if i can get query string, perhaps i can render it.
How can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get `querystring`  from url
and then get data from string via [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function.
code:

```
$str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$str = str_replace(":","=",$str);
parse_str($str, $get);
echo $get['name'];
echo $get['age'];
```